# How should I validate age( 2 Digit) in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working on form validation in Kotlin(Android), i have to pass data one Activity to Another activity with validation.
So , i want to know how we validate age(2 Digit) and it will be pass on another Activity.

i want ,when user enter his/her age the validation should take input of 2 digit if it is true it will pass to next Activity otherwise data is not passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got an answer,

```
    // Validate age format
    val agePattern = Regex("^(0?[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])$")
    if (!userAge.matches(agePattern)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a valid age between 1 and 99", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        return
    }
```

This code totally work